# Which versions of Struts2 support the @include_page Freemarker tag?

Tags: web-applications, struts2, annotations, freemarker

The Freemarker [documentation](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html#pgui_misc_servlet_include) notes:

```
...some Web Application Frameworks don't use FreemarkerServlet, so include_page is not available.
```

Struts 2.1.6 seems to support the @include_page annotation, but I upgraded to Struts 2.1.8.1, and it doesn't seem to support it. Does anyone know definitively which version of Struts2 supports the @include_page annotation?

I am interested mainly in versions higher than 2.1.6.

Comment: Why don't use the `<@s.include value="file_name" />` or `<#include "file_name" />` ?

Comment: <#include "file_name" /> doesn't work for JSP. I didn't think of <@s.include value="file_name" />, I might give that a go. @include_page would still be nicer though.

Comment: Hmm actually it seems <@s.include value="file_name" /> is just as nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about it.

As per [Ischin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227804/lschin)'s suggestion, just use this as a nice alternative:

```
<@s.include value="file_name" />
```